# Importing SVG-symbols into QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, import, svg

[image]I'm trying to import downloaded SVG-Files into QGIS to use them as layer symbols, but nothing works. This question was asked before, but unfortunately, the suggested solutions don't work.

When I do

> "Settings->Options->System->SVG Path"

And open the folder, there are no files in it. The only way I can access those is by opening the folder without any QGIS involved, click on the files and open them in a browser, then it shows me the symbol, but after hours of trying I didn't find any possibility to import them into QGIS.

I only can open them in the browser-window, but not add them as a layer. When right-clicking on properties it says under the headline "Meta Data": Error.

It would be very nice if someone could help me. I may try to figure out the problem more extensive.

Comment: Have you tried setting the SVG for each layer directly via Properties > Single Symbol > SVG Marker, and changing the directory (Click on: "...") to the exact SVG file you wish?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use SVG symbol as layer, but SVG may be use to symbolise a layer.

If your svg are some geographic feature (shape of a country or continents) they are probably made for use with vector graphics software (like illustrator or inkscape) not with GIS. if that is the case you should try to find the same data in another format suitable for use with gis software.

If you want to use your svg to symbolise a layer adding the svg path allow you to access your svg in the layer styling panel when you select the svg symbol type

Comment: No, those are symbols for the layer style like houses, trees and so on, provided for being used with GIS.

Comment: So  after going to Settings->Options->System->SVG Path and setting the svg path to the folder that contain your svg you just have to load a point layer, go to the layer styling panel , clic on the 'simple marker' symbol and change the symbol type to svg marker and you should be able to see your new svg...

Comment: It doesn't work, the folder is shown as empty and when choosing svg marker at the layer styling panel it doesn't contain or show a symbol, just a question mark appears.

Comment: after choosing svg marker you could try to navigate to your svg folder using the button at the bottom of the layer styling (just under the svg image box) and see if you can select an svg. If that didn't work it's probably an incompatibility between qgis and your svg, you could try to open your svg in a vector graphic software and edit them.....

Comment: Not all svg files are valid for QGIS. I used Inkscape and saved svg files as "Plain SVG" to use them in QGIS. Can you show us one of your svg files?

Comment: Is there a possibility to upload a file?

Comment: Try to add one into your question as an image. imgur should be able to import svg files.

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't work. I just uploaded a file I transformed into png